# Need eventlistener for .click so that dynamically refreshed buttons work, but actions multiply

Tags: jquery, ajax, event-listener

I have a page where one div:s content (not the whole page) refresh/reload/update if I make changes to the database.

This content contains a table with rows that contains some text and buttons. Since I need the buttons to still work with the `.click` I added an eventListeners. The problem is that the first time I press one of the buttons inside this div it's as it should be, but for every time I press one of these buttons the actions multiplies.

It's like there are too many eventListeners. But I need to create them so that every button is clickable. How would you solve this?

My brain tells me that I need to delete the other eventListeners (because one is created every time I click, right?) and then trigger a new one. But I don't know how to do that.

My code looks something like the code below. So the first time I press 'Edit' I get one 'Hello'-alert, the second time I get two 'Hello'-alerts, the thirt time I get three 'Hello'-alerts...... etc

HTML

```
<div class="div-to-reload">
    <?php
        // Loop Through Database {
            echo '<td><p>Some Info</p></td>';
            echo '<td><button class="edit-button">Edit</button></td>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var setupEventListener {
        $('.edit-button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            someFunction();
        });
    }

    function someFunction(){
        // update database with ajax and on success:
        alert('hello');
        $('.div-to-reload').load(document.URL + ' .div-to-reload', setupEventListeners);
    }

    setupEventListener();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to replace your

```
var setupEventListener {
    $('.edit-button').click(function(){
        e.preventDefault();
        someFunction();
    });
}
```

with something like this

```
$(".div-to-reload").on('click', '.edit-button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        someFunction();
    });
 );
```

this way you will have a single handler for all buttons.
This is not tested but should work.

Comment: This is correct in terms of answer (+1), but will trip a error (or fail to prevent default) because e is not defined. But then that is a fault in the OP's design of their event listeners. The e (event object) needs to be local.

Comment: I tried this and it totally works! I hade to do some serious brainwork since my code is much more complex than the one shown above, but it finally works! (for now, I always manage to bump into problems...) Thank you!

Comment: Didn't bump into any error or fail with the prevent default. @Pebbl

Comment: @Pixeldoris — you won't get an error in your code, but if Catalin's code is used stand-alone it will trip an error. In your code your use of `e.preventDefault()` won't do anything, because you are operating on the event object from the dom-ready/page-load event (in the previous scope)... in fact it may work, but only for older versions of Internet Explorer, where the Event object was globally shared between all events. In anything more modern it won't error, but it will have no effect. Just move the `e` to inside the local event handler and you'll be fine.

Comment: I just realized that the code I wrote here is different than my real code when it comes to the `e`. So I updated it here too. @Pebbl :)